# import excel data to database in angularjs

Tags: mysql, angularjs, codeigniter

I am trying to read and insert excel file data to mysql database table using angularjs( front and) and codeigniter (back end).thanks in advance

included xlsx-reader.js
this is only the excel file read code it is not working.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="App">
        <div ng-controller="PreviewController">
            <div class='form-group'>
                <label for='excel_file'>Excel File</label>
                 <button class="btn btn-link" type="file" ng-model="file"ngf-select ngf-change="importToExcel()">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span>ImportExcel
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

app.js

```
(function(undefined) {
    App.factory("XLSXReaderService", ['$q', '$rootScope',
        function($q, $rootScope) {
            var service = function(data) {
                angular.extend(this, data);
            };
                service.readFile = function(file, showPreview) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                XLSXReader(file, showPreview, function(data){
                    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    });
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            };
            return service;
        }
    ]);
}).call(this);
```

controller.js

```
angular.module('App').controller('PreviewController', function($scope, XLSXReaderService)
{       
         $scope.showPreview = false;
        $scope.importToExcel= function(files) {
        $scope.sheets = [];
        $scope.excelFile = file[0];
        XLSXReaderService.readFile($scope.excelFile, $scope.showPreview).then(function(xlsxData) {
            $scope.sheets = xlsxData.sheets;
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: has anybody found an answer for this? I am trying to do the same thing but using PHP as the back end thanks